# Resetting passphrase on booted and unlocked LUKS2 partition?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, password-recovery, luks

I have an Ubuntu server 20.04 install with LUKS enabled.

While trying to add an extra key it no longer accepted my old passphrase.
I've tried many times with:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen --test-passphrase /dev/vda3
```

but always get:

> No key available with this passphrase.

It's setup to need the passphrase at boot time, but the machine is booted and the partition is unlocked, and I have the root password.
Is there anyway to reset the passphrase?

I've made a backup of the data, but I'd really prefer not to have to reinstall the server.